# ¿Cómo podría dejar el botón en azul el de contactos, y bordear los cuadrados del formulario?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

El botón de contacto lo quiero poner a la inversa que los otros dos pero no hay manera, me sale en amarillo también. Y los bordes en el formulario no sé cómo ponerlos con las esquinas redondeadas.
[image: Tengo que dejarlo así!!]

Os adjunto el index.html para que veais cómo lo hice.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo-header">
            <img src="/Logo_ILERNAOnline.png" alt="">
        </div>
    <nav class="nav-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Cursos</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Formulario-->
    <hr>
    <form class='contacto'>
        <h2 class="formualario">Formulario de contacto</h2>
        <div><label>Nombre:</label><input type='text' value=''></div>
        <div><label>Apellidos:</label><input type='text' value=''></div>
        <div><label>Telefono:</label><input type='text' value=''></div>
        <div><label class="cajaTexto" for="address">Mensaje:</label></label>
        <textarea rows='4'></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Enviar'></div>
    </form>
    <!--Pie De Pagina-->
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-contenido">
            <p>XXXX</p>
            <p>XXXXXXX</p>
            <p>SMIR</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

---

perdon me dejaba el archivo css3

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none
}

/* HEADER */

a, li{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:black;
}

.logo-header img{
    margin-left: 52px;
    width: 130px;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 4rem;
}

.nav-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0rem 10.75rem;
}

.nav-menu li{
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
    color:white;
}

.nav-menu li {
    background-color: #FEC940;
    border: 8px solid
    #FEC940;
    padding: 0.25rem 1.75rem;
    border-radius: 1.0rem;
}
.nav-menu li:hover{
    background-color:
    #00B9D0;
    border:8px solid
    #00B9D0
}


/* Formulario */
.contacto{
    margin-left: 85px;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 45px 45px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.contacto label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.contacto input[type='text']{
    padding: 7px 6px;
    width: 294px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.contacto textarea{
    padding: 7px 6px;
    width: 294px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.contacto input[type='submit']{
    margin-left: 85px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 4px solid #FEC940;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #FEC940;
}
.contacto input[type='submit']:hover{
    background-color:
    #00B9D0;
    border:4px solid
    #00B9D0
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .cajaTexto{
    width: 180px; 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
/* Pie de pagina */
footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #595959;
    height: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.footer-contenido{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-contenido p{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style:italic;
    color:#fff;
}

/* SETEO DE COLORES */
menu{
    color:#FEC940
}

elementos{
    color:#00B9D0
}

textos,footer,titulo{
    color:#595959
}
```

Answer (score 0):

como estas? Aqui te adjunto el codigo un poco corregido, tal vez no de la manera mas correcta ya que no queria modificar mucho tu codigo, pero hay varios errores, de todas formas puede pasar, espero que te sirva la ayuda y cualquier duda o consulta no dudes en hablarme. Te felicito por casi llegar al resultado e intentarlo. Saludos Al4stor

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 1 rem = 10px */    
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 2;
}

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none
}

/* HEADER */

a, li{
    color:black;
}

.logo-header img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20rem;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 3rem 1rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navegacion {
        display: flex;
        gap: 2rem;
    }
}
.navegacion__enlace{
    border: 4px solid #FEC940;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    background-color: #FEC940;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
} 

.navegacion__enlace:hover{
    border: 4px solid #00B9D0;
    color: white;
    background-color: #00B9D0;
}

.navegacion__enlace-contacto{
    border: 4px solid #00B9D0;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    background-color:#00B9D0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.navegacion__enlace-contacto:hover{
    border: 4px solid #FEC940;
    color: black;
    background-color:#FEC940;
}


/*Te dejo tu codigo comentado para que veas las diferencias en los resultados*/
/*.nav-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0rem 10.75rem;
}

.nav-menu li{
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
    color:white;
}

.nav-menu li {
    background-color: #FEC940;
    border: 8px solid
    #FEC940;
    padding: 0.25rem 1.75rem;
    border-radius: 1.0rem;
}
.nav-menu li:hover{
    background-color:
    #00B9D0;
    border:8px solid
    #00B9D0
}


/* Formulario */

/*Hecho por vos
.contacto{
    margin-left: 85px;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 45px 45px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.contacto label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.contacto input[type='text']{
    padding: 7px 6px;
    width: 294px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.contacto textarea{
    padding: 7px 6px;
    width: 294px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.contacto input[type='submit']{
    margin-left: 85px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 4px solid #FEC940;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #FEC940;
}
.contacto input[type='submit']:hover{
    background-color:
    #00B9D0;
    border:4px solid
    #00B9D0
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .cajaTexto{
    width: 180px; 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
*/

/*Hecho por mi*/  

form {
    width: 300px;
  }

  button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .formulario {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 5rem auto 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 5rem;
}
.campo {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.campo__label {
    flex: 0 0 9rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px; /* Ancho del label, ajusta según sea necesario */
    margin-right: 10px; /* Espaciado entre el label y el campo de entrada */
    vertical-align: top;
}
.campo__field {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 120px); /* Ajusta según el ancho del label y el margen derecho */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}


/*Aca se le da estilos al boton por separado*/
.boton{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding:0 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
    border: 4px solid #FEC940;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FEC940;
}

.boton:hover{
    border: 4px solid #00B9D0;
    background-color: #00B9D0;
}


/* Pie de pagina */
footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #595959;
    height: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.footer-contenido{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-contenido p{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#fff;
}


/* SETEO DE COLORES */
menu{
    color:#FEC940
}

elementos{
    color:#00B9D0
}

textos,footer,titulo{
    color:#595959
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo-header">
            <img src="Ilerna-Logo-2-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <nav class="navegacion">
            <a href="#" class="navegacion__enlace">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#" class="navegacion__enlace">Cursos</a>
            <a href="#" class="navegacion__enlace-contacto">Contacto</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Formulario Hecho por vos
    <hr>
    <form class='contacto'>
        <h2 class="formualario">Formulario de contacto</h2>
        <div><label>Nombre:</label><input type='text' value=''></div>
        <div><label>Apellidos:</label><input type='text' value=''></div>
        <div><label>Telefono:</label><input type='text' value=''></div>
        <div><label class="cajaTexto" for="address">Mensaje:</label></label>
        <textarea rows='4'></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Enviar'></div>
    </form>
    
    Siempre te recomiendo hacer los navs de forma directa, no en forma de lista porque no es el mismo formato-->

    <!--formulario hecho por mi-->
    <main class="formulario">
        <h2>Formulario de contacto</h2>
        <form class="formulario-form">
            <div class="campo">
                <label class="campo__label" for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input class="campo__field" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" />
            </div>
            <div class="campo">
                <label class="campo__label" for="email">Apellidos:</label>
                <input class="campo__field" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" id="text" />
                <div class="campo">
                    <label class="campo__label" for="Telefono">Telefono:</label>
                    <input class="campo__field" type="number" placeholder="N° telefono" id="telefono" />
                </div>
                <div class="campo">
                    <label class="campo__label" for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
                    <textarea class="campo__field campo__field--textarea" id="mensaje"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="campo">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="boton" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </main>

    <!--Pie De Pagina-->
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-contenido">
            <p>XXXX</p>
            <p>XXXXXXX</p>
            <p>SMIR</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>



<!--Hay muchas cosas por cambiar y corregir, 
las que agregue o cambie yo tal vez no esten del todo bien 
porque lo hice de manera rapida sin querer modificar mucho tu codigo
para que veas las comparaciones y el uso de ciertos elementos, 
de todas formas te felicito por haber llegado a un resultado similar, 
espero que te haya servido mi ayuda, 
cualquier consulta o lo que necesites hablame y te ayudo. Suerte colega-->
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe en tu respuesta qué cambios has hecho. Es difícil leer las correcciones solo por comentarios en el código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.